# Determine the area of the inner loop of the following polar curve

Tags: calculus

Determine the area of the inner loop of the following polar curve $r = 3 - 6 \cos(\theta)$

Answer (score 1):

the answer requires (at some point) integrating
$$\int \cos^2 \theta d\theta$$

recall that
$$\cos 2\theta=\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta$$
$$\cos 2\theta=\cos^2\theta-(1-\cos^2\theta)$$
$$\cos 2\theta=2\cos^2\theta-1$$
$$\cos^2\theta=\frac{\cos 2\theta+1}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\cos 2\theta + \frac{1}{2}$$

I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you know exactly what area is to be determined ?

A little drawing will avoid a lot of mistakes !

[image]